# nullpointer exception in starting tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

my tomcat server is not starting in eclipse which was working fine before but now its showing the following exception.
although its working quite fine outside eclipse. but whenever i try to start the server, the following exception occurs and it shows the message =
 " starting Tomcat server v8.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem"

```
Dec 08, 2014 4:35:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 08, 2014 4:35:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: please provide complete stacktrace

Comment: This stacktrace might be a result of previous error. Posting full stacktrace helps.

Comment: sorry just saw the whole stack trace.
haven't seen it first. it was concurrentexecutionexception.
the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, it was because I had misconfigured my Tomcat server.  Deleting it and creating a new server entry helped.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace seems to show that Tomcat has already decided that the startup has failed, and that the NPE occurred while trying to shutdown.

I expect that the real problem (i.e. the one that caused Tomcat to abandon the startup attempt) is earlier in the log file.

---

Indeed the Tomcat source code confirms this:

```
protected void releaseCaches() {
    this.keyCache.clear();
    this.nioChannels.clear();
    this.processorCache.clear();
    if ( handler != null ) handler.recycle();
}
```

A NullPointerException here means that `keyCache` or `nioChannels` or `processorCache` is `null`.  (I think) that can only happen if something went wrong during the construction of the `NioEndPoint` object because those three fields are `private final`. Or at least, they are in the version I looked at.